# Expose private case class in Scala

Tags: scala, compilation, defensive-programming

I have a situation where a codepath is given some `Path`'s which it uses to query a database. It so happens that *sometimes* some of these paths need to go through a translation service, to map them to updated `Path`s before the query. Essentially the simplified flow is

```
val paths: List[Path] = getPaths()

val pathTranslationOpt: Option[Map[Path, Path]] = getTranslationOpt()

paths.foreach { p =>
  val pathToUse = 
    pathTranslationOpt
      .flatMap(_.get(p))
      .getOrElse(p)

  someFunctionsUsingThePath(pathToUse)
}
```

I'm worried about a situation in which someone accidentally calls `someFunctionsUsingThePath` with `p`, forgetting to perform the translation. This could be caught at compile time modifying the code slightly

```
val paths: List[Path] = getPaths()
 // let NewPath be a case class defined in the scope of the translate function as 
// case class NewPath(path: Path)
val pathTranslationOpt: Option[Map[Path, NewPath]] = getTranslationOpt()

paths.foreach { p =>
  // Have the function explicitely take a NewPath so the user cannot forget to call the translation service
  someFunctionsUsingThePath(
    newPathOpt = 
      pathTranslationOpt.flatMap(_.get(p)),
    fallbackPath = p
  )
}
```

This seems to be safer to me, as forgetting to call the translation service results in a compile time error. However, a negligent user could simply pass in `Some(NewPath(p))` to the function call, defeating the purpose.

**Is there a way to make `NewPath` such that it can be used freely, but only constructed from the translation call?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
case class NewPath private(path: Path)

object NewPath {
  def apply(path: Path): NewPath =
    NewPath(
      pathTranslationOpt.flatMap(_.get(path)).getOrElse(path)
    )
}

def someFunctionsUsingThePath(path: NewPath) = ???

paths.foreach { p =>
  someFunctionsUsingThePath(NewPath(p))
}
```

`NewPath` can only be created via the `apply` method in the companion object, which translates the path if necessary but otherwise leaves it unchanged.